# How to find the source and the destination in each data flow task for every package in the solution?

Tags: ssis, dataflow

I have hundreds of SSIS packages that are not documented.  I'd like to come up with the code/program to list all data flow tasks in every package in the given solution.  The list should include:
Package Name, Data Flow Task Name, Source Connection or Source DB, Source Table/File, Destination Connection or DB, Destination Table.

Is it doable?

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely write this using the correct version of the SQL Server binaries and your favorite .NET language to do so.

I did a lot with SSIS in my life and I would absolutely not want to write that as there's such a variety of ways a package could be drafted. Things you'll discover is that every container might contain a Data Flow and there can be data flows in places they don't belong, like an Event Handler. And there may be COM to deal with.

There were paid for tools on the market at one point: BI Documenter (I think that was the name) was one. The open source project BIDS Helper which has since been rebranded had some documentation functionality in it.

But, by far, hands down the absolute best way to handle it and the only approach I would advocate is that you use Biml for a project like this. Biml, is the Business Intelligence Markup Language, it's a domain specific language that reduces SSIS (and tables and cubes) to the smallest unit. And then allows you to query over it.

Step 1. Download [BimlExpress](https://varigence.com/bimlexpress) It's a free add-in for Visual Studio. You will use this to reverse engineer all your SSIS packages into the corresponding Biml

Step 2. Right click on the project and select Add new Biml File

Step 3. Write the Biml

I used the following query in a recent project because we needed to extract source queries (Postgres) and then the target tables in SQL Server. The source query bit assumes there are Expressions on the data flow so not included.

```
<#
string dataflowName = "";
string sourceComponentName = "";
string targetComponentName = "";

// Loop through all the packages
foreach (AstPackageNode p in this.RootNode.Packages)
{

    // Find all the Data Flows on the canvas itself
    // Your TODO: inspect the containers via  p.Tasks.OfType<AstContainerTaskNode>() looking for dataflows
    foreach (AstDataflowTaskNode t in p.Tasks.OfType<AstDataflowTaskNode>())
    {
        // TODO: Lots of gotchas here, 
        // What if there are multiple sources
        // what if the source doesn't support "names" for the table/query
        // What if the package was built via Import/Export wizard which has 
        //  several independent source to destinations all within the same DFT
        // etc
        // Same applies to destinations

        dataflowName = t.Name;
    
            // This is an example of how to iterate through all the OLE DB Destination components identifying various bits I needed to know
            foreach (AstOleDbDestinationNode tn in t.Transformations.OfType<AstOleDbDestinationNode>())
            {
                // What connection is being used
                WriteLine(tn.Connection.Name);
                // Extract table best we can
                System.Xml.Linq.XElement xe = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(tn.GetBiml());
                foreach (System.Xml.Linq.XElement node in xe.Elements().Where(xnode => xnode.Name == "ExternalTableOutput"))
                {
                    tableName = node.Attributes("Table").FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString().Split('.')[1];
                    // Table will end up looking like either [srcdb].[foo] OR "srcdb"."foo"
                    tableName = tableName.Substring(1, tableName.Length-2);
                }
                // What if we need columns?
                // <Columns><Column SourceColumn="id" TargetColumn="Id" />
                foreach (System.Xml.Linq.XElement node in xe.Elements().Where(xnode => xnode.Name == "Columns"))
                {
                    foreach (System.Xml.Linq.XElement inode in node.Elements().Where(xnode => xnode.Name == "Column"))
                    {
                        WriteLine(inode.ToString());
                        WriteLine("");
                    }
                    WriteLine("");
                }
            }

#>
```

For the way the BimlExpress works, you need to either have all the packages open (so_69215306.biml as my image shows) and the various WriteLine(s) will show in the preview panel.

[image]

When you want to attempt to do this across your whole ecosystem of packages, then you'll want to multi-select in the Miscellaneous section of Visual Studio and then right click on your inspector script (for my screenshot, that would be BimlScript6.biml) and Check Biml for Error or Generate SSIS package.

Both will have the same effect - assuming you're just using Biml for the object model capability. Instead of WriteLines which are helpful for debugging, I assume you'll write to a *something* json/csv/txt/database/whatever

Step 4. Fall in love with all the power of Biml and buy BimlStudio

Example of converting a project to Biml

- Convert to Biml
- Select the project and [Import] (this identifies what you *could* bring into the Biml project definition)
- Select the assets you want to [Add to Project] (likely everything)
- Right click on project and choose
  [image]

Comment: Thank you.  I installed BimlExpress and attempted to follow the steps, but I am getting errors in the code you sent as an example.  I have never written Biml codes, so I am not even sure how to troubleshoot.  Do I paste it between <biml> tags?  Is there a configuration I need to activate to make it work?

Comment: Sorry, hazard of copy pasting code. Yes, I had missed the `<# #>` blocks in my sample code and they would go between the biml tags. Start small, like just the basic package enumeration my screenshot shows and ensure you have that piece working and then go to the next thing (what tasks/containers are in my packages? How do I want to actually document this as I assume Print messages aren't going to cut it)

Comment: Do I need to convert my dtsx packages into biml format before running the code?  I've seen people saying I need to reverse engineer my SSIS into biml, but there is no explanation how it should be done.  Do I just right click and convert to biml?  Also, can I run the code without creating an SSIS package?  If I use Start button, I get a message that debugging is not supported.

Comment: Thank you for your patience.  My question is how to I move my SSIS packages to the Miscellaneous section and reformat them into biml?

Comment: Right click on the project and BimlExpress should provide an option of `Convert SSIS Packages to Biml`

Comment: I've tried that.  It creates a BimlScript.biml file.  If I have it open and check the script for errors, nothing happens.  I am not getting a list of packages, it just gives me a 'no errors" message, and the preview panel is empty.

Comment: I updated with an animated gif showing the clicks

Comment: Thank you, this is a great explanation.  The only thing I did not catch is how you compiled it.